# VisualStudio InheritancePicker with Solution Folders

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, solution

Has anyone of you ever had the problem that when you try to create a new "User Control" with Visual Studio, that the grid with the possible classes to choose from is just empty?

I'm having this problem now. Everything worked just fine until i created some "Solution Folder" in my VS-Solution. I made this folders to structure my solution, because it has grown big over the time. I can still compile the solution, everything works just fine. The only problem I'm facing is that I can't create any "User Control" anymore. The "Inheritance Picker Window" is just empty... I could choose the assembly that contains the needed UserControls manually via "Browse..." but that is not a good solution, because it will have to statically reference the dll. I could also make the inheritance myself, without the "wizard" but then I'd have to edit the designer file to match the parent class...and that is nothing I want to do...

This problem only occurs when I have these "Solution Folder" in my solution. When I have all the projects on the same level without folders, then the "Inheritance Picker" works fine...

Is this a bug in VS (happens in 10 and 12), or am I doing something wrong?